# In wpf what is difference between Text and SelectedValue properties of a combobox

Tags: wpf-controls

I am new to WPF. I have a problem with ComboBox that is placed within a cell of a grid. I am using xceed grid control. Within the xcd:CellEditor tag, I have this ComboBox control. The combobox is populated with values properly with required value in it selected but when I click on the combobox, the selected value is cleared (showing empty selection) and I had to click on the dropdown arrow to display the list and select that value again.

This problem is occuring to me when I am using the Text property of the ComboBox but when I replace the Text to SelectedValue then I don't see this problem. Can anyone throw some light on this.

Following is what I have changed.

From `Text="{xcdg:CellEditorBinding}"` to `SelectedValue="{xcdg:CellEditorBinding}"`